# How can I get the Total every month?

Tags: php, sql

I'm doing the dashboard for our system. I want to add a bar graph which displays the total transaction every month from January to December this year. Can somebody help me with my problem? This is my query.

```
  SELECT tbl_barangay.barangay_name, 
   tbl_transaction_details.supplier_medicine_id, 
   tbl_supplier_medicine.medicine_name, 
   SUM(tbl_transaction_details.total_price) as 'Total' 
  FROM 
   tbl_transaction_details 
  INNER JOIN 
   tbl_supplier_medicine ON tbl_transaction_details.supplier_medicine_id = 
   tbl_supplier_medicine.supplier_medicine_id 
  INNER JOIN 
   tbl_transaction ON tbl_transaction.transaction_id = 
   tbl_transaction_details.transaction_id
  INNER JOIN 
   tbl_barangay ON tbl_barangay.barangay_id = tbl_transaction.barangay_id 
  WHERE 
   tbl_barangay.barangay_id = 1 
  AND 
   tbl_transaction.transaction_date BETWEEN "2019-08-18" AND "2019-08-18"
  GROUP BY
   tbl_transaction_details.supplier_medicine_id
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your database schema well but can you please look into this line?

```
tbl_transaction.transaction_date BETWEEN "2019-08-18" AND "2019-08-18"
```

I think this is one of the reasons that are causing problems because the transaction date is not selecting the whole year dates.

Also, the `GROUP BY` clause should contain all columns except the aggregation columns. 
So, the `GROUP BY` clause should be like this,

```
GROUP BY
   tbl_barangay.barangay_name, 
   tbl_transaction_details.supplier_medicine_id, 
   tbl_supplier_medicine.medicine_name
```

Hope, this helps. Thanks.